# Install cordova plugin once imported to Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I'm trying to install a cordova plugin to a project which has already been imported to android studio.
If I run:

```
cordova plugin add wifiwizard
```

It says:

```
Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
```

How do I correctly install this plugin, without having to start again?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a Cordova project

```
cordova create nameOfProject
```

Then you go to this project (cd nameOfProject) and you add in this folder the plugin you want as you did it.